# A vueltas con una composición UML

Tags: sql, uml

Siguiendo con unas pautas que me han dado tengo una duda en la relación entre unas entidades, me dicen lo siguiente:

> Se desea almacenar información sobre los deportistas que participan en las diferentes pruebas. Cada deportista tendrá asignado un código alfanumérico único, nombre y apellidos, fecha de nacimiento, sexo y nacionalidad. Cada deportista que participa en una prueba puede hacerlo a título individual o representando a un club, que puede ser diferente para cada prueba en la que participe.
>   Todo club, como entidad que es, se identifica por un código alfanumérico y tiene asignado un nombre y, posiblemente, una página web. Además, de los clubes queremos almacenar la localización de su sede mediante sus coordenadas (longitud y latitud).
>   Tras la participación de los deportistas en las diferentes pruebas, se desea registrar el dorsal con el que han competido, el puesto en el que han quedado clasificados y la marca o el resultado obtenido.

Lo he planteado de la siguiente manera:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

El tema es que me entró la duda de meter una relación ternaria entre la entidad "prueba","deportistas" y "club" y a su vez asociando estas a una entidad asociativa con los resultados que obtiene el atleta.

Quizás es todo mas sencillo de como lo planteo pero tengo dudas.

Comment: Hazte el modelo ER, lo verás mucho más claro... http://dia-installer.de/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

La semántica que defines yo la modelaría así, porque tampoco llego a ver un vínculo especialmente estable entre un deportista y su club. De ser así, añadiría una relación adicional `representan` entre clubes y deportistas, pero da la sensación de que los deportistas sólo representan a clubes en pruebas concretas. Los resultados y dorsales asignados no hace falta que los modeles como una entidad aparte, pueden ser atributos de la relación `compiten`.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: mas o menos lo que tenia pensado,mucho mas claro así sin duda.

Comment: No hay secreto: a modelar se aprende modelando... :) Cuantos más modelos hagas, mejor te saldrán. ¿Cómo sabes que estás modelando bien? Pues cuando, al programar que es cuando se hace uso del modelo, dejes de detectar errores de diseño... El resto es teoría que no dirá nada hasta que no lo experimentes por ti mismo. Vamos, como la vida misma :) Ánimo con ello, y vota lo que guste, que tienes 20 al día, úsalos ;)